# Изготавливать или изготовлять?

Tags: глаголы

Интересно, как, по-вашему, правильно писать - ИЗГОТОВЛЯТЬ ИЛИ ИЗГОТАВЛИВАТЬ? Встретил объявление "Мастерская изготовляет стулья". Мне глагол ИЗГОТОВЛЯЕТ "порезал глаз". Думаю, что правильнее было бы написать ИЗГОТАВЛИВАЕТ. А Вы что думаете по этому поводу? Можно было бы обойти "неудобное" слово

Comment: @Александр Цаплин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: "порезал глаз" режет ухо

Comment: Ещё так можно: "Мастерская **производит** стулья".

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что из допустимости обеих форм не следует их равноправие в смысле взаимозаменяемости, поскольку они различаются по практике употребления ("изготовлять" гораздо реже применяется). Не всегда выбор между этими словами делают сознательно, но во многих типичных случаях люди уверенно выбирают одну из форм слова - "изготавливать", причём альтернатива им кажется просторечной (как в вопросе). Как быть в примере с предприятием? Если отвечать на вопрос о том, чем занимается предприятие (каков его профиль), мало кто усомнится в выборе:

"**предприятие изготавливает** арматуру, вот чем он занимается - всё время находится в этом процессе".

Для чего нужна вторая форма несовершенного же вида - неужели слово возникло оттого, что у кого-то когда-то так случайно вышло? Можно было бы порассуждать о "богатстве красок" языка от разнообразия суффиксов, но можно поискать и функциональное отличие этого слова - какой информативный оттенок оно несёт? Думаю, что и в случае того же "предприятия" употребление второго слова возможно - в форме предложения услуг:

"**предприятие изготовляет** на заказ нестандартные виды арматуры".

Это может означать, что предприятие, помимо своей повседневной деятельности (оно изготавливает напр. серийные металлоизделия), время от времени выполняет заказы - если таковые поступают. Принимает их и выполняет, закончив изготовление заказанного - это ограниченное во времени результативное действие, в отличие от повторяющегося процесса, в котором предприятие постоянно пребывает.

Такой трактовке (различия ограниченного во времени и длительно повторяющегося действий) не противоречит и старое значение слова изготовлять ("приготовлять"). Это значение сохранилось не только в литературе (гуглом можно найти "налима", которого призывают скорее начать "изготовлять", причём кто-то уже "изготовляет" к разжиганию дрова), но и в современном военно-морском уставе. "Корабль к бою и походу изготовить" - по этому приказу экипаж начинает (я бы сказал) "изготовлять" корабль. Ведь мы, говоря о приготовлении пищи, обычно имеем в виду однократный, хотя порой и растянутый процесс ("приготовляем" то или иное блюдо и употребляем или подаём его гостям). О том  что где-то "приготавливают" пищу мы довольно редко слышим - это, скорее, из жизни работников общественного питания (они изо дня в день заняты этим непрерывно).

Таким образом (без особой строгости в разграничении употребления), я бы отнёс "изготовлять" к однократному или просто ограниченному во времени действию изготовления чего-л., а "изготавливать" - к систематически повторяемому такому действию или процессу.

Answer (score 2):

> Интересно, как, по-вашему, правильно
> писать - ИЗГОТОВЛЯТЬ ИЛИ
> ИЗГОТАВЛИВАТЬ?..  что думаете по этому
> поводу?

Что можно сказать? Словари приводят эти варианты как равноправные. Говорят и так и так.

> Можно было бы обойти "неудобное"
> слово?

Можно. Например, так: ***мастерская по изготовлению** чего-л.*

Answer (score 0):

Есть существительное "изготАвливание" и "изготОвление". Думаю, и глаголы есть разные. На мой взгляд, первое существительное указывает на конкретный процесс, а второе - на длительное действие, т. е. изготовление арматуры в принципе на нашем заводе, в отличие от изготавливания вам на заказ.
Меня смутил другой глагол. Закаливать-закалять. Существительное "Закаливание" есть, а вот слова "закаление" - нет. Но есть закалка...

Comment: Глагола-то два, согласен. Но дальше-то что? И почему одно существительное указывает на более длительное? Старайтесь писать более развернутые ответы с изложением своей логики.

Comment: Про "закалять" Вы вполне можете задать отдельный вопрос. Делать это в ответах не следует.

Answer (score 0):

Раньше в словарях не было слова «изготавливать», только «изготовлять». Но малограмотные граждане использовали «изготавливать» в разговорной речи, и со временем эта форма закрепилась как равноправная «изготовлять». В настоящее время по использованию слова «изготавливать» можно вычислять людей, которые этого не знают.

Comment: *Раньше*, конечно, растяжимое понятие, однако категорическое утверждение "в словарях не было" неверно: В Словаре Ушакова это слово есть, с пометой *разг.* Кстати, оно встречается уже в 1833 году в "Последнем Новике" И. И. Лажечникова. И зачем кого-то вычислять по употреблению слова *изготавливать*? И главное - что вам дает это? Изготавливать - литературное слово.